# which function for filtering TRUE/FALSE in a list in R

Tags: r, list, datatable, subset

I have two lists:

```
test1
$`0`
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.005401506 in referenceBasedPrice."

$`1`
[1] TRUE
```

and

```
> test2
$`0`
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.005401506 in referenceBasedPrice."

$`1`
[1] "some text"
```

I want to keep only those lists elements that are NOT `TRUE`, for which i have written:

```
> test1 = test1[-which(sapply(test1, isTRUE))]
> test1
$`0`
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.005401506 in referenceBasedPrice."
```

but it doesnt seem to work properly on the second list, which doesnt contain any TRUE:

```
> test2 = test2[-which(sapply(test2, isTRUE))]
> test2
named list()
```

Why is it not working for the list `test2`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Data
test1 <- list(`0`="Mean relative difference: 0.005401506 in referenceBasedPrice.",
              `1`=T)
#Code
lapply(test1, function(x) x[!isTRUE(x)])
```

Or this:

```
#Code 2
unlist(lapply(test1, function(x) x[!isTRUE(x)]))
```

Note that you have lists and not dataframes.